# Prove that if $Re(z)>0$ then $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}| \ge 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

This is probably a very basic question in complex numbers.

First define $\sqrt{w} := \sqrt{|w|}e^{i(Arg(w)/2)}$ where Arg is the principal argument function.

Prove that if $Re(z)>0$ then $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}| \ge 1$ with equality holds only when $z \in (0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$.

There is also a hint given that I haven't managed to prove:

Hint: first check that $Re(\bar{z} \sqrt{z^2-1}) \ge 0$ for every z under consideration.

Comment: $\sqrt{w} := \sqrt{|w|}e^{i(Arg(w)/2)}$

Comment: Yes. I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Assuming $z=\cosh w$, then:
$$ \left|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right| = \left|\cosh w\pm\sinh w\right|=\exp\left(\pm\text{Re}(w)\right)$$
so you just have to study the map $w\to\cosh w$.

Comment: This question appears at the very beginning of the book - first chapter, first section, much before any complex mappings are learned.
Only very basic operations such as Arg, |z|, $\sqrt{z}$ are learned.
Do you have another way to prove it without using cosh?

Comment: @amirbd89: as an alternative, you may consider that $z+\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is a root of the equation $$ t^2-2zt+1 = 0.$$